# Convert HTML output of a PHP script to PDF?

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I have two files located in `localhost/invoice` named `x.php` and `template.php`,
and then I have a URL like this:

> localhost/invoice/template.php?name=wawan

How can I convert the output page into a PDF? What I want is to access `x.php` and then get the converted `template.php`. I tried using mpdf, but it doesn't work.

Here's `x.php`:

```
<?php
include("MPDF54/mpdf.php");

$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','' , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list

$mpdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents('template.php?name=wawan'));

$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

And this is `template.php`:

```
<div> The name is :
<?php


echo $_GET[name];

?>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  How doesn't it work?  Is the output incorrect?  What's wrong with it?  Do you get an error message?  If so, what does the error message say?

Comment: You may want to check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
# Capture the output of the page:
ob_start();

$_GET['name'] = 'wawan';

require 'template.php';

$content = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

# Write the captured HTML to the PDF:
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
```